# power BI aggregate some columns and not others (like in a pivot table in excel)

Tags: powerbi

I would like to do a basic thing in Power Bi, I have a table with rows labelled and columns which are delivery month in the future (recognized as date type). For the moment what I have is a table displaying all columns, Aug 22, Sep 22, [...] Oct 23, Nov 23, Dec 23.

I would like to keep the 2022 months as it is now but I would like to aggregate the 2023 months in one column, 2023. In excel, we can do a pivot table and then play with the filters on the top of the pivot table but with power BI I'm strangling doing this simple manipulation.

Does anyone knows how to do it without doing new columns and using DAX ?

Many Thanks !!

Comment: You can do this in Power Query (the Query Editor of Power BI).  There are a variety of methods to accomplish this, depending on what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this functionality does not exist yet in the Power BI Matrix.
The best alternative option is to switch your axis for now and have your dates in the rows.

The idea has been submitted for review, if you wish to vote for it you can do so here:
https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=151a8279-d892-4e52-8cec-4f3b69bdbc6c